# I need some help clearing up a problem with sorting a Priority Queue+linked list in Java

Tags: java, linked-list, priority-queue

Hello
I am trying to implement a Priority Queue in Java from scratch with a linked list but I am having a problem sorting elements on insertion. Here is my program thus far, any help would be massively appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class T0 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        PQ myList = new PQ();

        myList.addSort("Z");
        myList.addSort("B");
        myList.addSort("C");
        myList.addSort("B");
        myList.addSort("Z");

        System.out.println(myList.view(0));
        System.out.println(myList.view(1));
        System.out.println(myList.view(2));
        System.out.println(myList.view(3));
        System.out.println(myList.view(4));
    }
}


class PQ {

    Node tail = new Node(null, null);
    int elementCount = 0;

    Node lastAdded = tail;

        public void add(String word) {
        Node added = new Node(word, lastAdded);
        lastAdded=added;
        elementCount++;
    }

    public void addSort(String word){
                Node temp = new Node(null, null);
        for(int n = 0; n<elementCount && word.compareTo(lastAdded.next().toString()) >1; n++){
            temp=lastAdded.next();
        }
        Node added = new Node(word, lastAdded.next());
        lastAdded.changeNext(added);
        elementCount++;
    }

    public String view(int i){
        Node temp = lastAdded;

        for(int n = elementCount; n > i; n--){
            temp=temp.next();
        }
        return temp.toString();

    }
    public String toString() {
        return lastAdded.toString();
    }



    class Node {

        String name;
        Node nextNode;

        public Node(String s, Node n) {
            name = s;
            nextNode = n;
        }
        public void changeNext(Node n){
            nextNode=n;
        }
        public Node next() {
            return nextNode;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return name;
        }
    }
}
```

Currently outputs:

```
   run:
Z
B
C
B
Z
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

Upadate: 
Changed addSort to be:

```
    public void addSort(String word){
            Node temp = lastAdded;
for(int n = 0; n<elementCount && word.compareTo(lastAdded.next().toString()) > 0; n++){
    temp=lastAdded.next();
}
    Node added = new Node(word, lastAdded.next());
    lastAdded.changeNext(added);
    elementCount++;
    lastAdded=temp;
}
```

This throws a null pointer exception at

```
System.out.println(myList.view(0));
```

Comment: Please let us know what the exact problem is, i.e. what is the output of your program.

Comment: Make some efforts to clarify your problem to let people help you.

Comment: It looks like a task from a school/university. Is it?

Comment: @Roman The problem is that addSort does not sort, just add. I just added an output from the program

Comment: @Skarab Yep. I spent a few hours yesterday pulling my hair out over it

Comment: @Michael, I added the `homework` tag - please use it in the future for school assignment related posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the loop

```
    for(int n = 0; n<elementCount && word.compareTo(lastAdded.next().toString()) >1; n++){
        temp=lastAdded.next();
    }
```

you are always comparing the new word to the same element, instead of iterating through the list *(1a)* (and you keep assigning `temp` the same value inside the loop *(1b)*). **[Update]** And you compare the output of `compareTo` to 1 instead of 0 *(2)*. Thus - depending on the implementation of `compareTo` - the result may *always* be false. (AFAIK it would not be for [`String.compareTo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29) specifically, since it can return values greater than 1 - but this is not guaranteed in general.) **[/Update]**

And then, regardless of the result of your checks, you always add the new element after the last added element *(3)*.

However, since you don't adjust `lastAdded` *(4)*, it will keep pointing to the same element (`tail`), so in effect `tail` will always be the *first* item in your list, not the *last*.

**Update 2:** in your updated `addSort`, you fixed issues (2) and (4) above, but (1a-b) and (3) are still there.

Part of the problem is that for a singly linked list to work, you need to keep a reference to its *head* at all times - otherwise you have no way to walk through it! You are sort of trying to use `lastAdded` for this purpose, but this is just mixing two different things, causing further confusion. Note that you don't actually need a reference to the last added node - this information is of no use when you are about to insert the next element into the list. I recommend bringing a dedicated `head` reference into the picture, and changing the code accordingly (and dropping `lastAdded` unless you are sure you are going to need it later). Note that this does not eliminate the need for (4) - even if you have a `head` reference only, you still need to modify it (although not always - only when inserting at the beginning of the list).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I replaced my for loop with this one but the program is still outputting the letters in the order which I am inputting them.

Comment: @Michael, not surprising, since the loop above is a straight quote from your code ;-) Btw would you mind telling us the output at last? You know, we can sure guess (or copy your code into an IDE and run it), but giving more info would help you get better answers faster...

Comment: Right- sorry. My output is:
Z
B
C
B
Z
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second) EDIT: These are all on new lines but I do not know how to do that in stack overflow comments

Comment: I tweaked it to be like this, but it throws a null pointer exception at line 17 (print myList element 0):  edit: added code to OP

Comment: @matt b I tried to upboat him but I dont have enough stack-overflow-karma to do so,

Comment: @Péter Török Keep being awesome!

Answer (score 0):

In the `addSort` method you are assigning a `Node temp` to (what seems to be) the place you want to insert the node - but then you do not use this reference again after the for-loop.

Comment: This used to not be the case but I changed it while debugging. Anything I do with temp throws a null pointer exception.